# magento dataflow profile product import bug

Tags: product, upload

i imported product in magento via data flow profile, csv got uploaded , and i am able to see all product in admin but it not show in frontend , but when i edit that product in admin can click save with out making any changes product starts showing of frontend,

i searched lot but could not find any proper solution to this

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is compare the products in the database before and after clicking save to see what happens.

Common problems are as follows:

1. website linking,
2. category linking,
3. stock item,
4. store linking,
5. indexer (if you have this set to on save then the importer may not run it but saving the product may),